Linux user logs bad encoding (Fedora 39)
. Hello guys, I have this weird formating in my user logs, anyone know where it is coming from ?
Thanks.
G�O`��NMESSAGE=17:19:31.502 › did-navigate-in-page�2�R���     ��\�Ek�D��F���Y$#+y���=��8@9 9�9x9�9x9�9�       9p
9 
  9�
�\�Ek�D��F���Y�\6�+7��8@9 9�9x9�9x9�9�  9p'w����N8�NMESSAGE=17:19:32.216 › Sending IPC message: updateNotification�2�7���I�
9 
  9�
�\�Ek�D��F���Y2q��:���8@9 9�9x9�9x9�9�  9p��`�&���Nh�NMESSAGE=17:19:32.217 › handleIPCBadge, update badge value 591�29:�����
9 
  9�
9�l9q9�K:�oA�pAHqA�qA��E��E��E��E0�E��Nu[�]Q돦���N��NMESSAGE=17:19:42.408 › Open link in browser�2��:���c��\�Ek�D��F���Y����٭��8@9 9�9x9�9x9�9�     9p
9 
  9�
9�l9q9�K:�oA�pAHqA�qA��E��E��E��E0�E�Ns[���V����N_STREAM_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX�]P01G�N�N_PID=82647�2��<��נ��\�Ek�D��F���Y|�e�_e�[��8@9 9�9x9�9x9�9�    9p
9 
  9�
9�l9q9�K:J@�J@0K@�K@H�@��E��E0�E0�N��N�%� ^2��C�N0�NMESSAGE=17:20:02.825 › Sending IPC message: updateNotification�2�Gr��$���\�Ek�D��F���Y6s�����     ��8@9 9�9x9�9x9�9�      9p
9 
  9�
9�l9q9�K:�oA�pAHqA�qA��E��E��E��E0�E��N�!:�~��t���N`�NMESSAGE=17:20:02.828 › handleIPCBadge, update badge value 591�2�Or������\�Ek�D��F���YnUZ�_5���8@9 9�9x9�9x9�9�  9p
9 
  9�


What user logs? Perhaps it is not a straight ascii file & nor is it meant to be. Systemd journal files are binary, not ascii.


One possibility is the file is being read using the wrong encoding. For example, in Kate,

You can change the current encoding using the menu items Tools → Encoding and try different options, or
You can overwrite the defaults in Settings → Configure Editor...


Another possibility is that some  machine commands are embedded in that log. For example, the string ��8@9 9�9x9�9x9�9� occurs repeatedly. Could those be printer escape codes or other machine control codes?


